# How many burns does it take to reboost the ISS?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, orbital-maneuver, reboost

When the International Space Station is given a reboost, how many burns are performed?  Is it a Hohmann transfer orbit, with one perigee burn and one apogee burn?  Or is it one burn at apogee just to raise the perigee?  Something else?

Comment: In more ways than one, a question for Hohmannfan.

Comment: This has always bothered me. If it was a complete one-orbit 92 minute burn I would have assumed that it's a spiral outwards to a larger circle, but I think they are only like 20 to 40 minutes long. *Interesting!*

Comment: Not an expert, but I doubt they care about Hohmann. Boosts happen so often and they only are a few m/s and last somewhere around a third to half an orbit, so no advantages from Oberth effect. There's a related answer with links that I think covers it well: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/how-often-does-iss-require-re-boosting-to-higher-orbit.